# Now and forever

Tags: grammaticality

> I want you to be with me only two
>   times in my life.. now & forever

I came across this sentence the other day, and thought that the usage of "two times" for "now and forever" is incorrect, since forever encompasses now. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Now and forever" is a [common phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_and_Forever).  This sentence is supposed to be witty, specifically *because* the "now and forever" part does not fit the reader's expectations of what "two times" will be.

It is a play on words, and isn't supposed to follow formal logic. Even if the sentence were changed to:

> I want you to be with me only one time in my life: forever

It still wouldn't be logically correct, because *forever* is not a specific time — it is infinite.

Comment: Too bad you've hit the rep cap for today, I'm upvoting you in vain...

Comment: @RegDwight: I guess I'm on a roll today.

Answer (score 2):

It's a joke. It's like counting "me, myself, and I" as three people: it deliberately uses words in illogical and thus unexpected ways. Note that the sentence is fully grammatical, so in that sense it *is* correct.

Comment: Please bear with me Martha, but how is the sentence grammatical and hence, correct?

Comment: @fuz3d, there's verb tense & number agreement, the sentence structure is properly formed, none of the words are misspelled - if you just look at it from a parts-of-speech standpoint, everything looks fine. Hence, grammatical.

Comment: @fuz3d: notice how Martha *didn't* say "grammatical and hence correct"; she actually said "grammatical, so in that sense it is correct". Even complete and utter nonsense can still be grammatically impeccable. Check out ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) or ["’Twas brillig, and the slithy toves / Did gyre and gimble in the wabe; / All mimsy were the borogoves, / And the mome raths outgrabe."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky)